# Can't sync using Leedroid

Tags: sync, gmail

I have been using Leedroid for a while and all is well, it works great. Now for some reason my GMail is reporting that I have 7 unread emails, but my GMail app won't update my inbox on my phone.

I've tried going into the settings and resyncing the accounts, but the button doesn't seem to do anything.

Any ideas please?

***Update***
It seems that I have lost all my sync functionality. I can no longer sync my GMail, Calendar or Google Contacts with the web. Happened on 17 Feb 2011. Perhaps Google have stopped people updating?

Would I be better to just reflash my phone?

***Update 31 Mar '11***
This has happened again now, and I can no longer sync up anything on my phone. Does anyone have any ideas please? Should I swap from using LeeDroid over to a stock HTC rom?

Comment: I connected my phone to my PC, as disk drive, and the phone hung, then rebooted itsself, and now it's synced again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My phone will not sync if I have low space warning in my notification bar. I've cleared out the data of a bunch of apps which were hogging my internal memory and as soon as I had cleared the low space warning my phone sync'd!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to clear the data for Gmail Storage in `Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications`.  For some reason the Gmail app occasionally thinks it has synced some messages and does not re-load them from the web, so you need to clear data so it will load everything from scratch.

Comment: Okay, I gave this a try and now my Inbox is empty, but it doesn't seem to sync. I'm not getting a sync icon, and am still not able to manually force a sync.

Comment: OK, now that's strange.  Did you change your password?  Possibly you need to clear data for Gmail also so it will pick that up ... might help anyways too.

Comment: +1 Gmail often stops syncing on my very busy work account, clearing data works for me.

Comment: I've cleared data for Gmail, but I can't find how to remove the GMail Storage